# Delete an element from peewee Query select

Tags: python, select, peewee

I have a Query result by Peewee's table.select(), lets say that I want to delete a part of the resulting list(QuerySelect) how is that done? or exclude certain elements from the query?

```
#Edited
result = users.select();
for element in result:
   for name in list:
      if(element.name == name):
          removeThisElement()
```

I want to exclude a list of names from the query result

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Deleting this element in the database?

Comment: i don't want to delete it from the database, i want to remove it from the current selected list. Let's say i don't want a certain user list that i have determined from being in the selected list lets say they are all company members and those selected members aren't authorized in a certain place, as in unauthorized list and a full company list

Comment: Doing it in Python really does not make sense since that is what SQL is for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [coleifer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30359104/4890577) said, since you're using peewee, use SQL to do it, so according to your last edit, the solution should be:

```
result = User.select().where(User.name.not_in(a_list_of_names))
```

although list comprehension also works:

```
result = [user for user in Users.select() if user.name not in a_list_of_names]
```

---

Documentation: [Query.where](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Query.where)

Comment: this works on a single user which is amazing, but how can i apply it to a list?

Comment: if i could remove a specific element after querying i would be able to exclude list elements, changed the sample code

Comment: @Newbie try `result = [user for user in users.select() if user.name not in list_of_names]`

Comment: What about filtering out the unwanted user in the query itself, e.g. `User.select().where(User.name != 'whatever')`

Comment: @coleifer It works when you want to exclude a certain user form the query, but the question seems to exclude a number of users from the query. Right?

Comment: Then you can write `User.select().where(User.name.not_in(['name1', 'name2', 'name3']))`. I just have no idea why you would suggest doing it in Python ??

Comment: @coleifer Ah, I've already edit the answer yesterday and suggest using SQL first, the same way as you.

Answer (score 1):

The best and most proper way would be to use SQL to do this:

```
User.select().where(User.name != 'myname')
```

Then your resulting list is pre-filtered.

---

If you wanted to filter out a *list* of names, then you could write

```
names_to_exclude = ['lord63', 'Newbie', 'etc']
users = User.select().where(User.name.not_in(names_to_exclude))
```

Comment: i wanted to filter out a whole list, lord's code does that

Comment: I updated my comment. If you're using an ORM and SQL, why on earth would you do the filtering in Python is what I'm trying to understand? You truly live up to your name, Newbie ;)